# Hibernate 6.2 and CTE issue

Tags: java, hibernate, common-table-expression

I tried to use CTE support in Hibernate 6.2 but faced strange behavior.
So here's my code to query all the categories:

```
            TypedQuery<Category> typedQuery = em.createQuery(
                    """
with categories as(
    select a as category from Category a
)
select d from categories d 
                    """, 
                    Category.class);
```

HQL query seems correct but when I execute it I receive an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.query.derived.CteTupleTableGroupProducer cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedModelPart (org.hibernate.query.derived.CteTupleTableGroupProducer and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitTableGroup(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3887)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitRootCte(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3629)
```

Documentation doesn't mention this case so it's unclear whether it's bug or per design.

If I remove alias and change query to

```
with categories as(
    select a from Category a
)
select d from categories d
```

I got another exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component at index 0 has no alias, but alias is required
```

So the only way to workaround that is pretty ugly query:

```
with categories as(
    select a.id as id from Category a
)
select c from categories cat join Category c on cat.id=c.id
```

Comment: The error messages aren't very good, so I'd appreciate if you could create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issues. The correct query would be `with ... select c.category from categories c`